# REST API for Sonatype Nexus v3.x

Tags: api, rest, nexus, sonatype

I can't find any information for using the REST API for Nexus v3.x (milestone 6 is the current latest), neither can I find anything in the UI that would take me to the API docs.

Anyone know mwhere I can find more information (I currently use the API extensively for automated config management of Nexus instances with v2.11.x) ?

Kind Regards

Fraser.

Answer (score 8):

I have talked to Sonatype Nexus engineers yesterday 06.01.2016 and they have informed me that:

- The REST API as of Nexus 3 Milestone 6 is not yet implemented.
- Using a browser to reveal and "clone" the calls to Nexus services makes also no sense, as in Nexus 3.x the REST API (when implemented) will be for programmatic access only, it will not be used by the UI. No effort will be expended in Nexus 3 making sure calls from the UI do not change from version to version. So using the UI calls to automate is not a good idea, and isn't going to be supported in Nexus 3.
- When implemented, the REST API will offer extended support for common and advanced operations. It will be much easier to call services than the equivalent in Nexus 2.x which required a bunch of individual calls.

There is a dedicated discussion on the topic  Nexus 3 REST API https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/forum/#!topic/nexus-users/eb7jeXKNgdU/discussion

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the REST API has been released as beta. You can get more information and give us feedback by going to this link: http://blog.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-new-beta-rest-api-for-content

For some of the config work, the Provisioning API might be a better match for now, but it would be good to give us feedback on what you'd like to control via the REST API as well.

Comment: Hi, sorry for this late comment. My team is currently running OSS 3.1.0-04, Build Timestamp: 2016-10-24-1137-57771. I understand that this version does not have a REST API. Could you please confirm this?

Comment: Why can't I GET beta API via curl or Postman? only Swagger works.
https://nexus.com/service/rest/beta/blobstores